# Live updates in ROOT

Tags: c++, plot, root-framework

I want to use [Root](https://root.cern.ch/) to draw a plot of time data. Those come from sensors that update at 10Hz. Can root cope with live updating graphs?

Comment: Not sure but conceptually, after data is added just redraw the canvas?
But the root forum might be the best place to ask for help: https://root-forum.cern.ch/

Answer (score 3):

on the root promt the following seems to work:

```
#include <unistd.h>
TH1F hist("hist","hist",100, -10,10);
TCanvas c;
hist.Draw()
for (int i = 0 ; i < 10000; i++ ) {
  hist.FillRandom("gaus",10);
  hist.Draw();
  usleep(100000);
  c.Update();
}
```

I haven't seen real life applications that update root displays at 10Hz, but "real time" plotting at lower refresh rates exists based on root in compiled applications for detector monitoring. (I don't actually know commonly used refresh rates, but if i had to bet it would be somewhere between 1Hz and 10Hz).

EDIT (example for compiled applications)

```
#include <TApplication.h>
#include <TCanvas.h>
#include <TH1F.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  TApplication theApp("App", &argc, argv);
  TH1F hist("hist", "hist", 100, -10, 10);
  TCanvas c;
  hist.Draw();
  for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    hist.FillRandom("gaus", 10);
    hist.Draw();
    usleep(100000);
    c.Update();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know we are not supposed to leave comments saying "Thank you". However, thank you for the code samples! ☺